# Hide LegacyExchangeDN as contact display in Office 365

Tags: powershell, outlook, migration, office365, exchange-server

I am using this guide created by Steven Goodman

http://www.stevieg.org/2010/07/using-powershell-to-import-contacts-into-exchange-and-outlook-live/

When importing .csv to Office 365 mailboxes with users created through local AD sync, the email address of the users in the same organisation, in the display email is shown as “xx xx”. External users email display name comes out as their email addresses.

However with uploading the same .csv to a non-AD synced email account, the display name appears as the normal email address.

Is there a way to show the emails in contacts, in the same organisation as their email addresses instead of this “LegacyExchangeDN”?

Answer (score 0):

When AD accounts are sync'd to O365, the cloud objects become "read only" for many of the properties, especially values like email addresses.

What should be done is to import the values to the on-premises accounts and allow the MS dirsync to push those updates up to the cloud objects.

However, you cannot just set *anything* and have it go up to the cloud.  The dirsync will only allow addresses that are in the list of accepted domains for the tenant and will purposely exclude non-smtp and non-x500 addresses.  this means that if you wanted to preserve an old RFAX (right-fax solution) address, you cannot push that value to the cloud.